# AR core unstable image tracking

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, tracking, arcore

We are developing AR contents using AR Core and Unity.  We have 30 marker images, when it plays it keeps shaking and being twisted so much.  Do anybody knows why?  if it is due to low recognition rate, is there any way to solve this problem?  We want to avoid using artificial marker like QR code.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons I could think of:1) low quality score for those images, 2) Bad light in the location where you test.
As recommended by sdk, your image score should be above 80 to work good